# Process trace tool for windows

Tags: windows, system-monitoring

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can show currently running processes and also can show the command line each process was started with. Is there a tool that can capture a trace of processes that were started and finished while the tool is running with the respective command lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process Monitor, also from SysInternals can do that:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

By default, the command line isn't shown, but if you right-click on the column headers and click on "Select Columns", you can add "Command Line" to the list of displayed columns.

Edit: If you haven't ever used Process Monitor before, it generates a *lot* of information. But, if you're looking for a particular *.exe or something, you can specify various filters so that you only get what you're looking for.

For example, if you wanted to just show the information for any cmd.exe processes, you can click on the filter button (Ctrl-L), and add a filter like this:

[image]

This is what needs to be selected to filter out process start / process exit operations you are after:

[image]